# Where does heat go at an atomic level in all phases of matter?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, atomic-physics, thermal-radiation

I'm trying to understand where heat energy goes in a substance. I've seen that mainly it's translation at lower temperatures, rotation at mid range, and vibration at high range, but I'm not sure of that. Someone made the claim that an atom can expand as it is heated, which I don't think is right, but in a way, this is a good description of black body radiation? Does anyone know some approximation of percentages for how much heat energy goes towards motion (translation, rotation, vibration) and how much is radiated as blackbody? And, does this change between the different phases: solid, liquid, gas, plasma? I'm just looking for a general concept here, so no constraints. If there's some special constraints to note, then please list them and the energy distribution within that particular system for comparison.

Comment: An atom in a molecule in a substance is different from an atom in a molecule in an ideal gas, which is different from an atom in a monatomic ideal gas. Trying to zoom in all the way to the atom as if the atom is a discrete, isolatable unit, is a category error.

Comment: Can you give an example of each case?

Comment: Respectively: a hydrogen atom in an ice crystal, the same hydrogen atom after heating the ice crystal in some water vapor at high temperature and low pressure, and a xenon atom in xenon gas.

Comment: atoms "expand" for a short period of time only. It then "shrinks" back transferring energy into other kinds of mechanical motions.

Comment: ok, so I'm wondering what your answer would be for each? For example, if you heat the H in ice, where does that heat go? is it vibrating the atom, exciting the electron, causing the H to move around in the ice? If it's a combination of these, approximately how much energy goes to each area? If it's vibrating, then the oscillating fields causes the blackbody radiation, right?

Comment: It excites electrons, then electrons relax back via thermalization transferring energy into vibrations.

Comment: I would vote against closing because this question points at a misunderstanding or misconception that is probably common when one think of heat as a property of the system, which can happen even unconsciously (due for example to the meaning of "heat" as "hotness" in the common language).

Comment: would any of you have a video or something to explain or show what happens at the atomic level? it sounds like you're saying that as a molecule collides with another molecule, the kinetic energy transferred excites the electrons, then they emit a photon and return to the base state. the kinetic energy of this molecule is greater though since it's been acted on by the external force of the collision. If so, how much of the energy in the collision goes towards simple kinetic movement (translation, rotation, vibration) and how much towards electrons emitting EM radiation?

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the day, heat is energy. Whether this energy is transferred by heat or by other means (i.e. work) is not what determines where it goes. What determines where the energy goes are the constraints that are applied to the system (think about phase transitions under different constraints such as constant $T$ or constant $V$ or constant $P$...).

Answer (score 1):

In thermodynamics, heat refers to the transfer of thermal energy between systems resulting from a temperature difference. There are three primary modes of energy transfer: thermal conduction, thermal radiation, and thermal convection, each exhibiting distinct characteristics at the microscopic level.

1. **Thermal radiation**. This process involves the emission of photons from one body, which are then absorbed by another body. At the atomic level, this absorption may occur when electrons in atoms transition between atomic energy levels, temporarily occupying excited states with larger orbital radii. However, these excited states are short-lived, as the electrons eventually return to their ground state. During this transition, the excess energy is transferred into various forms of mechanical motion, such as vibrational energy.
2. **Thermal conduction** In thermal conduction, bodies come into direct contact with each other, allowing for the transfer of vibrational energy from one atom to another. This mode of heat transfer is based on the principle that energy flows from regions of higher temperature to regions of lower temperature.

Regarding the thermal extension of bodies, at a microscopic level, the atoms or molecules in a solid are in constant motion, oscillating around their equilibrium positions. As the temperature of the material increases, the average kinetic energy of the atoms also increases, leading to more vigorous vibrations. This increase in vibrational energy causes the atoms to push against each other, resulting in a larger equilibrium interatomic distance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm wondering if the "thermal radiation" point you made accounts for the vibrating electromagnetic fields of the atoms? If most of the radiation is from excited electrons, wouldn't we see the quantized bands from specific orbitals? Why then would blackbody radiation only rely on the temperature of a substance?

Also, it sounds like your point of "thermal expansion" is showing that as the average speed of the vibrations increases, the average distance between the atoms increases?

Comment: it is statistics. You don't consider a single atom. The energy of the excited state is broadened by its motion and collisions with other atoms. Plank's formula is a statistical one. For black body radiation, it assumes many quantum states.

Comment: Black body radiation formula does not work for a single atom because it is not a black body.

Comment: The concept of temperature is a concept from statistical physics, it is not applicable for one particle.